# How can python-GDAL installed by Kyngesburye be recognized by pip?

Tags: python, gdal, pip

I am using macOS 10.12 and Python 2.7 installed by homebrew.
As recommended, I successfully installed [GDAL-1.11.4 by Kyngesburye's Framework](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks).

When I want to install another package which dependents on "GDAL>1.9,<2.0" using "pip install *.whl" or "python setup.py install", the pip do not recognize the installed GDAL. And of course, the pip will download and install gdal automatically.

Then, error occurs with " File "", line 4, in 
setuptools.sandbox.UnpickleableException: gdal_config_error(OSError(2, 'No such file or directory'),)"

Besides, when I edit my code using PyCharm, the GDAL is also not identified thought the code can run successfully.

I wonder how can I fix this problem?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178250/error-installing-gdal-python-package-on-a-mac
see this discussion, last post says: do not mix!

Comment: Thank you and I got it. So, I just remove the install_requires in the "setup.py" of my own python package. Then, it will be installed.